# In tradingview alert, when using {{strategy.order.comment}}, my comment is not showing but instead the strategy order id

Tags: alert, tradingview-api

In tradingview alert, when using {{strategy.order.comment}}, my comment is not showing but instead the strategy order id, why would be the case? Below is the exact script.

strategy.entry(id="Short", direction=strategy.short, stop=ShortEntry, comment="{"alertId": "ea581e08-d600-4fd9-b6a6-9185cfd5f737"}")

With {{strategy.order.comment}}, I would expect the alert message to show {"alertId": "ea581e08-d600-4fd9-b6a6-9185cfd5f737"} but the alert message shows as "Short" instead.. I have used this similar script for other alerts and works fine but this particular one acts strange... Please help!!

I tried changing the comment field for any changes but with no success (Still only showing the id part..)

Answer (score 0):

In general, use *comments* for the graph, and *alert_message* to send string by weebhook

Something like that:

```
if shortCondition
    strategy.entry(
      'Short',
      strategy.short,
      stop = ShortEntry,
      alert_message = '{"alertId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"}')
      comment = 'Short')
```

You could use the Placeholders *{{strategy.order.alert_message}}*, but I think it's not necessary in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try to recreate the alert with the same parameters you've used. Just remove the current one and set up a new one.

It seems the alerts're dependent on the version of your script. Once you've changed the script, the alert needs to be created again (instead of simply changing).

The source is here:
https://pinescripters.net/viewtopic.php?t=301