# Pine script `strategy.order.alert_message` is empty

Tags: pine-script, alert, pine-script-v5

I've got the following setup.

Pine script v5:

```
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, alert_message = str.tostring(syminfo.mintick) + " " + str.tostring(local_variable))
```

Tradingview alert settings editor (Message window):

```
"{{strategy.order.alert_message}}"
```

Expected output as an alert message (mintick value space local_variable value):

```
0.1 10
```

When the alert is trigerred I can see an empty string as a message instead of the values above.

What should be done in order to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to recreate the Tradingview alert with the same parameters you've used. Just remove the current one and set up a new one.

It seems the alerts're dependent on the version of your script. Once you've changed the script, the alert needs to be created again (instead of simply changing).

The same might apply to `strategy.order.comment`. Refer to [In tradingview alert, when using {{strategy.order.comment}}, my comment is not showing but instead the strategy order id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75287123/in-tradingview-alert-when-using-strategy-order-comment-my-comment-is-not-s/77617667#77617667)

The source is here: https://pinescripters.net/viewtopic.php?t=301